# Perl: curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: perl, debugging

[Perl Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682983/perl-script-updated-needed-unfamiliar-with-perl). I'm trying to get this script running in a debugger.

I've got Aptana + Epic + ActivePerl 5.12.4 working on Windows 7x64. The script is starting fine but I'm getting an error:

```
curl -sS http://intranet.mycompany.org/directory/directory.xml
```

The above command works fine... but if I start the debugger I get this error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

First part of the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = 'http://intranet.atlanticgeneral.org/directory/directory.xml';
my $output = 'C:\global.gabook';

my $file = "curl -sS '$url' |";
my $parser = new XML::Parser(Style => 'Tree');
my $tree = $parser->parsefile($file)->[1];
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's the extra single quotes around `$url` that's causing it.

Comment: It's a copy paste from a unix script that worked... I removed the single quotes around the '$url' and it now works in Aptana IDE. Post this as answer.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Windows doesn't like single quotes in commands. Try using double quotes in the command, using qq{} escaping. Just change one line:

```
my $file = qq{curl -sS "$url" |};
```

Comment: nice answer, single quotes are meant for mac or linux. In windows, replacing double quotes did the job.

Comment: Ubuntu didn't like single quotes as well.

Comment: Also seeing this on Ubuntu 14.04, when running curl in a QProcess under PyQt4. Double quotes fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: This is also true for back-slash \, that has to be converted into a slash / in cygwin

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/1322567/http-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl

Answer (score 3):

Wooble~

> "I'm guessing it's the extra single quotes around $url that's
>   causing it"

When I removed the quotes around the '$url' it worked. Quotes worked in redhat perl, but didn't work in my windows perl debugger:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = 'http://intranet.atlanticgeneral.org/directory/directory.xml';
my $output = 'C:\global.gabook';

my $file = "curl -sS $url |";
my $parser = new XML::Parser(Style => 'Tree');
my $tree = $parser->parsefile($file)->[1];
```

Posting as answer since Wooble didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when I was using the curl command in my java program as follows

```
    String command = "curl 'http://google.com'";
     try
       {            
           Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        .......
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

Changing command to the following fixed this error

```
      String command = "curl http://google.com";
```

Actually, It may be an issue because of shell interpretor. 
I used curl command like below example

```
String command = "curl  -duser.name=hdfs -dexecute=select+*+from+logdata.test; -dstatusdir=test.output http://hostname:50111/templeton/v1/hive";
```

Comment: Writing some curl scripts in groovy. This seemed to do the trick. Additionally  if you had any paramenters such as: -u user:pass then i could run the process just fine without adding intermediate quotes. So e.g. a command in shell:   "curl 'localhost:4502/path/to/servlet' -F 'file=@/path/to/file' " just becomes: "curl localhost:4502/../servlet -F file=@/../file" !

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (and not needing an external program), you could use LWP::UserAgent to fetch the document.

Comment: I am 100% not versed in Perl... I just know enough programming to understand what it's doing lol. The answer given to me on my original question does use LWP::Simple instead of Curl.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a wrongly spelled protocol part as in "htpt://example.com" or as in the less evident case if you prefix the protocol part with a space as in " http://example.com/".

Source : https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html