# indexing data in apache solr using bash script for curl

Tags: linux, curl, solr, cygwin

I am again posting the same question. Please help me in this problem.
Here is the code for the bash script that I have written

```
declare -i i=1
for file in searchdumps/*
do
echo "indexing $file"
i=$((i+1))
curl "'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=document$i&uprefix=attr_content&commit=true' -F \"myfile=@/home/test/$file\"" 
done
```

the path is correct the command when applied directly works, but when this script is executed there is an error

> indexing searchdumps/1.pdf curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or
>   disabled in libcurl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684235/perl-curl-1-protocol-http-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :-

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?stream.file=/home/test/$file&literal.id=document$i&commit=true"
```

Comment: ok i have tried this but this command is not indexing the text in the documents that was given. i want to know why my previous command is not working and this command is working using bash script